# Maximizing the probability of winning the prize in a game show

Tags: probability, optimization

> In a game show, there are three locked chests A, B and C. One of them holds a prize and the other
> two are empty. In a turn, the contestant chooses one of the chests and flips a fair coin. If the result is heads, he gets the contents of the chest else not. Given that chests A, B and C may contain the
> prize with probabilities of $\dfrac{8}{13}, \dfrac{4}{13}, \dfrac{1}{13}$ respectively and the contestant is given 2021 turns, then the number of times he must choose chest C to maximize his chances of obtaining the prize is:
> (A) 0
> (B) 155
> (C) 672
> (D) none

**My attempt:**
Let the number of times the contestant chooses chests A, B, C be $x$, $y$, $z$ respectively. Then, we have
$$\tag{1} x+y+z=2021$$
Now, if the contestant wants to open chest A, he must get at least one head out of $x$ tosses, in other words, we have to exclude the case where he obtains all tails. The probability that this happens is $1-\dfrac{1}{2^x}$. After opening the chest, the probability that he wins the prize is $\dfrac{8}{13}$. Thus, the probability that he obtains the prize from chest A is $\dfrac{8}{13} \left(1-\dfrac{1}{2^x} \right)$.
Performing a similar analysis for the other chests, the probability that he wins the prize is given by:
$$\tag{2} P = \dfrac{8}{13} \left(1-\dfrac{1}{2^x} \right) + \dfrac{4}{13} \left(1-\dfrac{1}{2^y} \right) + \dfrac{1}{13} \left(1-\dfrac{1}{2^z} \right)$$
The only thing left is to maximize $(2)$ under the condition $(1)$ and find the value of $z$ for optimum condition. I, however, do not seem to have any idea of how maximize the given function. Or perhaps, is there a simpler way to solve this?

Comment: Seems like an odd problem...the probability of missing all those times is so close to $0$...In any case, this is the same as minimizing $F(x,y,z)=\frac 8{13}\times \frac 1{2^x}+\frac 4{13}\times \frac 1{2^y}+\frac 1{13}\times \frac 1{2^z}$ subject to the constraint $g(x,y,z)=x+y+z=2021$.  Lagrange multipliers should work well.  Note:  it should, I think, be fairly clear what the approximate answer is.

Comment: @lulu I'm sorry but I didn't know what Lagrange's multipliers are till today. But after reading your comment, I did a bit of research into it. If I'm not wrong, I have to solve the equations, $ \dfrac{8ln2}{13 \cdot 2^x} =  \dfrac{4ln2}{13 \cdot 2^y} = \dfrac{ln2}{13 \cdot 2^z} = -\lambda $ and $ x+ y + z =2021$ which leads us to $x-3=y-2=z$. Thus, $x = 675$, $y=674$ and $z=672$. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Perfect!  Not bad for your first time working with the technique....It works particular well when, as here, there are no cross terms (the $x-$ derivative doesn't involve $y$ and so on).

Comment: @lulu I also noticed that we can solve this using $AM \geq GM$. The product of the three terms is a constant. The sum will attain its minimum when all 3 terms are equal. This turns out to be very similar to the method involving Lagrange multipliers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem description is somewhat ambiguous. If the contestant learns the result of the coin flip immediately, the correct strategy is to repeatedly choose chest A until the coin flips heads (if ever), then do the same with B and then with C.

If the contestant doesn't learn the result of the flip or has to pre-commit to her actions (which I assume is the intended version), one way to solve the problem is to compute the probability of obtaining the chest on a specific turn. If the contestant chooses A, this probability is $P_A = (\frac12)^x \cdot \frac8{13}$, where $x$ is the number of times the contestant has previously chosen A. Similarly, the probability for B is $P_B = (\frac12)^y \cdot \frac4{13}$. Since a greedy algorithm performs optimally in this problem, it suffices to choose options so that $P_A$ and $P_B$ and $P_C$ are all kept equally large. After choosing A once, $P_A$ shrinks to $P_B$. After choosing both A and B two more times, $P_A$ and $P_B$ both shrink to $P_C$. From here, they are  kept equally large by choosing them equally often. Thus, optimal play is such that $x = y + 1 = z + 3$.

Since $x + y + z = 2021$, this means that $3z + 5 = 2021$ so that $z = 672$.